# Does photoelectric effect play a part in the rotation of Crookes radiometer

Tags: thermodynamics, soft-question, photoelectric-effect

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCrnDGOl2xA), a person puts low frequency light in front of a Crookes radiometer, and the vanes don't spin. But they do when he puts a high frequency one. He then later makes some weird claims and connects it to the photoelectric effect. Ignoring all the pseudoscience in there, what really is the reason for this? Does the vane move due to expelling photoelectrons? Or does it have something to do with the absorption of certain wavelengths of light? How does the currently accepted thermal explanation of the spinning of Crookes vanes explain this?

I know the explanation of how a Crookes radiometer works. I just don't see how this observation fits in with that explanation.

Comment: Here's a clue: A Crookes Radiometer will not spin if the bulb is totally evacuuated. It needs a certain, small amount of gas in the bulb. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_radiometer#Effect_observations

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes I know that. But how does that explain it spinning only for certain wavelengths of incident light?